# Run command on Salt master before minion highstate

Tags: saltstack

Is there a way to run a command (or state) on the salt-master whenever `salt 'myminion' state.highstate` is run, but before the minion's highstate is executed?

The command is `svn update` or ([svn.latest](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.svn.html#salt.states.svn.latest)), so there will be files in /srv/salt available to the minion.  [svnfs](http://blog.mindfab.net/2014/04/saltsubversion-backend.html) won't work for me because of directory structure constraints.  I also found that you can't add custom filesystems (without modifying salt's source).

I was hoping the [Reactor](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/) system would help, but I am not sure if it can be used for this case.

EDIT:
Another possible solution is to write a SVN [post-commit hook,](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a custom runner that would execute your svn commands and then run your highstate as needed.

There are a lot of good example here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/tree/develop/salt/runners